# Bounce Contact Button move to the bottom

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using bouncehelp **Bounce Contact Button**, see [here](https://bouncehelp.com/#how-it-works)

Is there a way move it to the bottom of the page using css or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found

```
#bh_phone {
    bottom: 0;
    top: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove top position and add bottom for "div#bh_phone" id. otherwise insert following css code.

```css
div#bh_phone {
    top: unset !important;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: unset !important;
    right: 0px !important;
}
```